# Converting Qubits to +-1/2 Spin System for Expectation Value Calculation

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, measurement

I have a quantum system that consists of spin states with eigenvalues of +-1/2. However, in quantum computing, qubits are typically represented as states |0⟩ and |1⟩. I want to calculate the expectation values of operators on this spin system using the given code:

```
def find_expectation(op, psi):
    # Exact
    Exact = psi.adjoint().compose(op).compose(psi).eval().real
    # Sampled
    measurable_exp = StateFn(op, is_measurement=True).compose(psi)
    expectation = PauliExpectation().convert(measurable_exp)
    simulator = QasmSimulator()
    Sampled = CircuitSampler(simulator).convert(expectation).eval().real
    return (Exact, Sampled)
```

How can I convert the spin states of my system to the qubit representation (|0⟩ and |1⟩) so that I can use this code to calculate the expectation values correctly? (Or how can I convert my 0,1 system's results to spin system's results) Are there any specific transformations or considerations I need to take into account during the conversion process?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this conversion and ensure accurate expectation value calculations in the context of this code. Thank you!